# Some issues with chat box design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a chat application and I have two major issues in chatbox design.

1. I want some part of the screen scrollable just like other chatting applications when we have more messages we scroll up to see previous messages and other things are fixed on the screen like: sendbar,top-menu-bar, etc. but I unable to do so, I tried `overflow-y = scroll` but it didn't work.
2. As I mentioned in the first point some things have to be fixed on the screen but after setting `position = fixed` it also doesn't work.

I tried everything please help.

```js
function fxn(){
 
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value
  var ele = document.getElementById("parent")
  var foo = document.createElement("div")

  foo.innerHTML = "<div class = box1>" + text + "</div><br><br><br>";
  ele.appendChild(foo)
 
}
```

```css
#box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.out{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body id="bd">
  <div id ="box">
    Testing chat box
  </div>
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <div class="out">
    <input type="text" id="inp">
  <button onclick="fxn()">Send</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: hi Amrit, do you mean when a new message comes it should scroll auto?

Comment: @CodeBug yes, exactly but send bar should be fixed at the bottom.

Comment: okay check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function fxn(){
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value
  var ele = document.getElementById("parent")
  var foo = document.createElement("div")

  foo.innerHTML = "<div class = box1>" + text + "</div><br><br><br>";
  ele.appendChild(foo)
 ele.scrollTop = ele.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#parent{
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.out{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body id="bd">
  <div id ="box">
    Testing chat box
  </div>
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <div class="out">
    <input type="text" id="inp">
  <button onclick="fxn()">Send</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

please note here i had added height to the parent div and overflow-y to be scroll, and also added  `ele.scrollTop = ele.scrollHeight;` in the js part.

here you can read more about [ScrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Answer (score 3):

I see that the post has been accepted and it works nicely for the OP. But I would still like to present one more option. I just made CSS changes to make the footer fixed and header sticky so as to mimic your requirement.

```js
function fxn(){
 
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value
  var ele = document.getElementById("parent")
  var foo = document.createElement("div")

  foo.innerHTML = "<div class = box1>" + text + "</div><br><br><br>";
  ele.appendChild(foo)
 
}
```

```css
#box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.out{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body id="bd">
  <div id ="box">
    Testing chat box
  </div>
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <div class="out">
    <input type="text" id="inp">
  <button onclick="fxn()">Send</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! for this additional information, I will definitely add this to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function fxn(){
 
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value
  var ele = document.getElementById("parent")
  var foo = document.createElement("div")

  foo.innerHTML = "<div class = box1>" + text + "</div><br><br><br>";
  ele.appendChild(foo)
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
 
}

.out{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```